# Store pictures in H2 database spring boot thymleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf, h2

Good day. I want to store an image in an h2 database, then retrieve and display the same image in an html page. I am using spring boot and file upload method, but I am getting errors in the binding results

Here are the pages/classes:

Category.java

```
package com.vishal.project.entities;

@Entity
@Table(name="category")
public class Category implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ID")
private Long id;

@Size(min=1, max=90)
@Column(name="CATEGORY_NAME")
private String CategoryName;


@Lob
@Column(name="CATEGORY_PHOTO")
private byte[] CategoryPhoto;


public Category(Long id, @Size(min = 1, max = 90) String categoryName, byte[] categoryPhoto) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    CategoryName = categoryName;
    CategoryPhoto = categoryPhoto;
}

public byte[] getCategoryPhoto() {
    return CategoryPhoto;
}

public void setCategoryPhoto(byte[] categoryPhoto) {
    CategoryPhoto = categoryPhoto;
}

public Category() {}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
private Set<Book> Books = new HashSet<>();

public Set<Book> getBooks() {
    return Books;
}

public void setBooks(Set<Book> books) {
    Books = books;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setCategoryID(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getCategoryName() {
    return CategoryName;
}
public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
    CategoryName = categoryName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return "Category ID:" + id + 
           "Category Name:"+ CategoryName;
}


}
```

Categorycontroller.java

```
package com.vishal.project.web;


import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;
import com.vishal.project.entities.Category;
import com.vishal.project.services.CategoryService;
import com.vishal.project.util.Message;


@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/categories")
public class CategoryController {


private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BookController.class);

@Autowired
private MessageSource  messageSource;

@Autowired 
private CategoryService categoryService;

@GetMapping
public String list(Model uiModel) {
    logger.info("Listing categories:");
    List<Category> categories = categoryService.findALL();
    uiModel.addAttribute("categories", categories);
    logger.info("No. of categories: " + categories.size());
    return "categories";
}

@GetMapping(value = "/{id}" , consumes="Multipart/formdata")
public String show(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
    Category category = categoryService.findbyID(id);


    model.addAttribute("category", category);
    return "showCategory";
}

@GetMapping(value = "/edit/{id}")
public String updateForm(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("category", categoryService.findbyID(id));
    return "updateCategory";
}

@GetMapping(value = "/new")
public String create(Model uiModel) {
    logger.info("creating Category ...");
    Category category = new Category();     

    uiModel.addAttribute("category", category);
    return "updateCategory";
}


@PostMapping(value = "/upload")
public String saveCategory(@Valid @ModelAttribute("category") Category category, BindingResult bindingResult,
        Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
        Locale locale, @RequestParam(value="file", required=true) MultipartFile file) {
    logger.info("Creating Category....");
    logger.info("Category ID" + category.getId());
    logger.info("Category ID" + category.getCategoryName());
    logger.info("Category ID" + category.getCategoryPhoto());
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
    {
        logger.info("Error:", bindingResult.getAllErrors());
        logger.debug("field Error:", bindingResult.getFieldError());
        uiModel.addAttribute("message", new Message("error", messageSource.getMessage("category_save_fail", new Object[] {}, locale)));
        uiModel.addAttribute("category", category);
        return "updateCategory";
    }
    uiModel.asMap().clear();
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", 
            new Message("success", messageSource.getMessage("Category_save_success", new Object[] {}, locale)));
    //process upload file 
    logger.info("File Name :", file.getName() );
    logger.info("File Size :", file.getSize() );
    logger.info("File content type :", file.getContentType() );
    if(file != null) {
    byte[] filecontent = null;
    try
    {
        InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
        if(inputStream == null) 
            logger.debug("file InputStream is null");
        filecontent = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);     
        category.setCategoryPhoto(filecontent);
    }catch(IOException ex) {
        logger.error("Error Saving uploaded file");
    }
    category.setCategoryPhoto(filecontent);
    }

    categoryService.save(category);
    return "redirect:/categories/" + category.getId().toString();
}
```

}

[image: category Image]

categoryShow.page

```
<body>
<div th:replace="fragments/header_admin :: header_admin">Header</div>
<div class="container">

<h1>Category Details</h1>

<div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" th:object="${category}" >
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p class="form-control-static" th:text="${CategoryName}"> 
</p></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Category Photo</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p class="form-control-static" ><img alt="CatName" 
  th:src="@{CategoryPhoto}" /> </p></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

categoryUpdate page (create or update a Category with details and image)

```
<div class="container">

<h1>Category Details</h1>

<div>
    <form  class="form-horizontal" th:object="${category}" th:action="@{/categories/upload}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" th:field="*{CategoryName}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category Photo</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input name="file" type="file" class="form-control" th:field="*{CategoryPhoto}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div th:insert="~{fragments/footer :: footer}">&copy; 2017 Iuliana Cosmina & Apress</div>
```

The error : I am getting in bindingResult of CategoryController.saveCategory() method.

When I debug the code I am getting the error. Here's a pic to demonstrate:

[image]

I am having a hard time showing images on the CategoryShow page using thymleaf.
Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:** Can anyone tell me what this error means, please:

```
Failed to convert property value of    type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'byte[]' for property 'CategoryPhoto'; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.
StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'byte' for property
'CategoryPhoto[0]': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned 
inappropriate value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile'
```

**Final Update: I am getting this error : ** Required request part 'file' is not present

Comment: And what errors are you getting?

Comment: thank you for your reply. I just edited my Question. Sorry forgot to put which Error I was getting.

Comment: You can do it using multipart, [Here's](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-file-upload-example/) an example.

Comment: I get rejected value in Binding result

Comment: Please, dont post pictures of errors. Paste a stacktrace or error message log in your question.

Comment: I want to save the images and show the images in seperate pages after saving the new category

Comment: @Nikhil : The link you gave shows just how to save

Comment: To retrieve it just convert that byte array from database into Base64string and angular can read it directly `<img ng-src="'data:image/png;base64,' + {{yourbase64String}}" >`

Comment: I have updated the question. can you please tell me why am I getting this error : thanks for your time.

Comment: I am using spring Boot and thymeleaf

Comment: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "CategoryPhoto"
Now I am getting this error.

Comment: it seems like the problem is that your Object is expecting a byte[] but the post is a multipartFile. You should create  a CategoryDTO object that has your validation annotations on it but just for the non file fields. then in your controller create a new Category with the validated values and then do c.setCategoryPhoto(file.getBytes()) then persist that. because you have the form field and the object field have the same name it's trying to convert but can't

Comment: I think you should map the uploading action to a separate Controller endpoint.

Comment: Required request part 'file' is not present if I map it to different url

Comment: From a performance point of view, you should better store your images in the filesystem and only the references to them in a database!

Comment: there was a error in th controller method: Using Multipart file as I am uploading only one file it should be Part file instead of Multipart file.

Comment: There is a error Content type not supported.. when I try to view image any sugesstions?

Comment: @VishalTorne please check out my answer hope it helps

Comment: Issue Resolved thanks for help !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you always can do is to compare a working file upload [example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) with yours.

Another thing that will be helpful to compare your input names with the name your controller's method expect your file.

If your posted code is still relevant, you can find the name "Fileimport" on your file input in the template, but in your controller you expect file ( @RequestParam(value="file", required=false) ).

Other things that help you in debugging:

- using the developer tools of the browser and see what your are sending through the network
- log [incoming requests](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging) on server side (either in this way, or it is too complicated for you, you can simply iterate through the parameter names and log them (and if possible, their values too)

If this did not help on you, then please update the post: update your code (template + controller, if changed) and give use a better stacktrace: on better I mean you should show not just the last N line of the stacktrace, but at least to the first line where the execution goes through your code (in other words the class name starts with your package), even better if the first Caused by or the second if it is meaningful) is there.

Answer (score 3):

Spring translates uploaded files as [MultipartFile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html) objects, so you cannot map it directly to an array of bytes.

You can get a bytes array from a MultipartFile using [MultipartFile#getBytes()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getBytes--).

In your case, you could use an intermediate object (like a `CategoryForm`) where the field `CategoryPhoto` would be of type `MultipartFile`.
Then, in your controller, you map it to the `Category` object you already have using the method I showed above.

Comment: I see the point you are trying to make but why is it saying required file "not Present"  because I am uploading a JPG file. from your answer it should give error like object cannot be mapped or something like that.

Comment: I think spring is not able to recongnise or find the file which I upload

Comment: What did you change from your previous example to get this new error?

Comment: Just changed arguments to my controller method savecategory from multipart file to Part file as I am uploading one file at a time

Answer (score 3):

Hi your Thymeleaf form is resolved as follows the name attribute is removed if the th:field attribute is present

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/categories/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="id" name="id" value="" type="hidden">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="CategoryName" name="CategoryName" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category Photo</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input name="CategoryPhoto" class="form-control" id="CategoryPhoto" type="file">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Which clearly states the error you are getting even though you mention as name="file" in file input it is resolved to name=categoryPhoto because of th:field="*{CategoryPhoto}" mentioned after the name tag.

use th:value="${product.name}" th:name="name" th:id="name" instead of th:field it will more flexible

Answer (score 1):

The Issues are resolved Just tell you what I did in my Case:

1) If you are uploading one file in the page then use Part file as an argument to your post Mapping in the controller method

2) To my Second issue the image was not rendering in html page using thymeleaf because I am using byte[] to persist in my database. So it was not resolved by thymeleaf. So I used Apache commons binary codec Base64 (can be added as an Gradle or Maven dependency) to convert my byte[] image to Base64 String so that it can resolved by thymleaf.
like this:

```
    Category category = categoryService.findbyID(id);
    byte[] image = category.getCategoryPhoto();
    String CatImage =  Base64.encodeBase64String(image);
```

then in HTML

```
<img  th:src="@{'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+${Cimage}}" />
```

hope this helps someone !! thanks.